# How to enable listen in objective C(cocoa) to listen to the changes in database?

Tags: objective-c, real-time, rtmp, rtmfp

**Hi all**. 
I'm working on a cocoa desktop application.
I'm uploding a file to the server, Now i want the other users to get the notifications whenever i upload a new file from my app. and vice versa.. and whenever a file is uploaded to the server from other user from the same app i need to be notified at realtime.
I need to get latest updated file details. Can i use rtmp or something like that?
Is it Possible?
How can i do that? Pls anybody help me.

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Isn't RTMP/RTMFP supported by Flash Player/AIR only?

Comment: Its RTMP. Its not related to Flash/Air. I'm uploading image or pdf files. I want other users to get a notification at realtime when i upload the files. Is that possible or any other way to achieve that using sockets or so?